# VBA Excel Macro error: 1004 unable to get the substitute property of the WorkbooFunction class

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am using a vba macro to find a big string in a text file.
For that I read the text file , read the text to compare (which is saved in one of the cell). After that i would replace CRLF with CR (since the saved text does not contain CRLF). Then compare. Its working fine if the file size is less. But throwing the error when the file size is high (Around 50 KB is fine).
Any guess about the maximum size of the file?

The below part of the code is throwing error

```
  Open LogFilePath For Input As #iFile
  strFileContent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
  Close #iFile
  strFileContent = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(strFileContent, vbCrLf, "")
  strSearch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(strSearch, vbLf, "")
  strFileContent = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(strFileContent, vbTab, " ")   
  If InStr(1, strFileContent, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    SearchTextFile = "success"
  Else
    SearchTextFile = "failed"
  End If
```

[image]

Any guess or suggestion please.

Comment: I have just tested and there is a 32,767 byte limit on the size of the first parameter (and probably the other parameters).   I'm surprised that you have managed to get a 50Kb file to work.  As @AndyW suggests in an answer, use VBA's `Replace` function rather than `Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute`.

Comment: Total number of characters that a cell can contain: 32,767 characters. So I think `Substitute` is also limited. have a look at [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I was trying with files in size more than 200KB. Right now i checked with 32767byte and 32768 byte. 32768 showed the error but 32767 didn't show any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note the error refers to the Substitute property and that you are using Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute.

Personally, in VBA I always tend to use the REPLACE function which works in the same way.

I also use this when processing some large .txt files (20,000 rows/30MB) and don't encounter problems with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried Replace as you mentioned and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The `Substitute` is more for use e.g. with a cell formula. You should try following code snippet using `Replace` for your needs.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LogFilePath As String
Dim ifile As Integer

ifile = 1

LogFilePath = "D:/_working/application-log-file-small.txt"
strSearch = "Temp Path       :"

Open LogFilePath For Input As #ifile
  strFileContent = Input(LOF(ifile), ifile)
  Close #ifile
  '--- Show len of file content string -----
  MsgBox (Len(strFileContent))

  strFileContent = Replace(strFileContent, vbCrLf, "")
  strSearch = Replace(strSearch, vbLf, "")
  strFileContent = Replace(strFileContent, vbTab, " ")

  If InStr(1, strFileContent, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    SearchTextFile = "success"
    MsgBox ("success")
  Else
    SearchTextFile = "failed"
    MsgBox ("failed")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The replace function is working fine and I got the result.